# Ember.js test page keeps refreshing automatically

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I'm trying to follow an example integration test from here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/testing/testing-components/ (Testing Actions)

My problem is that the Test output keeps refreshing automatically, perpetually, for some reason?

**Test code:**

```
test('Can handle submit action', async function (assert) {
    /*
    * THIS TEST HAS PROBLEMS
    * THE PAGE CONSTANTLY REFRESHES FOR THIS TEST, NO IDEA WHY, NEED TO INVESTIGATE
    */
    assert.expect(1);

    // test double for the external action
    this.set('externalAction', (actual) => {
      const expected = {inputValue: 'test'};
      assert.deepEqual(actual, expected, 'submitted value is passed to external action');
    });

    await render(hbs`{{user-form inputValue="test" saveAction=(action externalAction)}}`);

    // click the button to submit the form
    await click('#submitButton');
  });
```

**Component.js:**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import {computed} from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  inputValue: '',
  submitText: 'Save',
  inputIsValid: computed('inputValue', function () {
    return this.inputValue.length > 3;
  }),

  actions: {
    save(inputValue) {
      if (this.inputIsValid) {
        this.saveAction(inputValue); // pass action handling to route that uses component
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**component template:**

```
<br>
<br>
<form onsubmit={{action "save" inputValue}}>
    {{#unless inputIsValid}}
      <div style="color: red" class='validationMessage'>
        Hey it is not valid!
      </div>
    {{/unless}}

    <label id="inputLabel">{{inputLabel}}</label>
    {{input type="text" id="input" placeholder=inputPlaceholder value=inputValue class="form-control"}}
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">{{submitText}}</button>
</form>
{{outlet}}
```

I thought it might be because the form in the template keeps submitting, but that can't be the case since it should only click submit once. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: you dont `preventDefault` the submit action, so submitting the form will reload the page (standard HTML behaviour)

Comment: @Lux That's not included in the Ember.js tutorial I was following. Could you give an example of how to implement `preventDefault` in this context? If your implementation works then reputation points for you ;)

Comment: You get the event as last argument to the action. The rest is standard JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Lux's suggestion written as comment; you need to do the following to prevent the form submission from reloading the page:

```
save(inputValue, event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (this.inputIsValid) {
    this.saveAction(inputValue); // pass action handling to route that uses component
  }
}
```

You receive the `event` as the last argument and call `preventDefault` tells the browser to not to handle the event as it would normally. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for a better explanation.

Comment: The last thing I would think of tbh I didn't expect it to work - but - it works!